# Why does Pavillion DV7 say "Boot Device not found"?

Tags: laptop, boot, hp-pavilion

I've installed a new hard drive and want to boot from the DVD drive to install the OS, but I get the following error:

```
Boot Device Not Found

Please install an operating system on your hard disk.

Hard Disk (3F0)
```

I've directed the machine to boot from the DVD drive, then from a USB recovery disk, but the message pops up every time.

Is this a problem with the HD? I did not replace the stock seagate with the same one. I used a Western Digital instead.

NOTE: I am not confused about F9 and Quick Boot. I have also done the changes in BIOS.

I thought maybe the DVD was broken, but even when I direct the boot sequence to the USB, it goes to the HDD.

Comment: I'm guessing its booting off the hard disk rather than the DVD for some odd reason. Chances are your HDD is perfectly fine, its something else

Answer (score 0):

Enter BIOS mode and check if your hard drive is existed. If not, your hard drive maybe dead or it disconnect to your main board.

If your hard drive working normal, check your boot priority device, make sure it boot from your hard drive

Comment: The Hard drive is does not have an OS installed.
The HD test indicate the drive is recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer seems to be set up to boot off the hard drive. To select the DVD drive as boot device:

1. Press the power button to turn on the computer and repeatedly press <kbd>F9</kbd> to get the boot device menu ([you may need to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> first](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01442956&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en#N75), then <kbd>F9</kbd>). Then select the DVD drive. This is a **one time change**.

   See http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&docname=c01443326 for more information on the boot device menu.
2. Press the power button to turn on the computer and repeatedly press <kbd>F10</kbd> to enter the BIOS setup ([you may need to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> first](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01442956&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en#N75), then <kbd>F10</kbd>). Then change the boot order so that the DVD drive is listed first. This is **a permanent change**.

   See http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&docname=c00034791 for more information on how to configure the BIOS.

Comment: I have already configured the BIOS to boot from the internal DVD.
Is it possible the DVD is broken?

Maybe.

But it also refuses to boot from the USB drive as well when I set it in the BIOS and in the Quick Boot.

Comment: Is the DVD drive listed if you press F9? Is the DVD spinning up?

Comment: It just says internal DVD. It spins up.

Comment: Yes, the DVD drive could be broken, but it could also be an issue with the disc itself. Is it a Windows DVD provided by HP or a recovery disc you created (check this link http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01867124&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en  for information on how to create a recovery disc)? Are you sure the DVD is bootable, can you boot another computer off the disc? If you still have the old Seagate hard drive around you could install it back and test both the DVD drive and the disc...

Comment: I used a Debian install disk to test the drive. A disk I used to successfully install linux on a desktop. Still ignores the DVD.
I tried a USB drive, AS I SAID ABOVE. Nothing. Still tries to boot from the HDD. The Seagate drive is damaged and not available for this process, hence the new drive.

Comment: I am using a Windows 7 boot DVD.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the problem was with the install disk.
I created a USB install disk and everything worked fine after that.